# Can Elasticsearch jdbc importer work with AWS hosted elastic service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nosql

I have a endpoint configured for a hosted Elasticsearch service on aws .Version of elastic search is 1.5.2 .I have used jdbc importer 1.5 to import data by specifying Elasticsearch {host,port and cluster} values .
Host key had value that of endpoint.
Port key had value 9300
and cluster key had the cluster name which i got on as a json response.

Any idea on this?
Any insights would be of great help.

It specifically gives NoNodeException

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to connect to the AWS ElasticSearch Service using the Transport Client for Java.  After much googling and head scratching I figured out that the AWS ElasticSearch Service is set up to listen on port 80.  See the following stack overflow question. [How to talk to aws elasticsearch service using elastic java client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558093/how-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-service-using-elastic-java-client)

Additionally to that they don't seem to support interacting with the service using the transport client and you have to use the Rest API over HTTP to communicate with the Elastic Search service. 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=681938

Comment: Basically I am trying to import data from mysql into elastic search using jdbc importer.Take a look https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc

Comment: There in json importer we have to mention elasticsearch server details to which we are importing . Keys such as elasticsearch.host,elasticsearch.port and elasticsearch.cluster.Any idea regarding what values for this key will work?

Comment: Maybe I read the question wrong.  Are you hosting an elastic search instance on AWS on an EC2 server or are you using the AWS ElasticSearch Service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS elastic service , then the url you have is the hostname and port is 80, and for cluster name you should hit that url then you'll get your clustername.

```
 {
"name" : "o__PCW8",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "GPo8f5PLRhKAWwJyLN8ffg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.0.0",
    "build_hash" : "8f0685b",
    "build_date" : "2017-11-10T18:41:22.859Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.0.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```